# How to ignore linux includes when building for android on Qt Creator?

Tags: android, c++, qt, cross-platform

##### How to ignore linux includes when building for android on Qt Creator?

Hi!, i'm trying to compile a project meant to be cross platform. this time for android on Qt Creator but Qt Creator it's including the X11 libs for linux that are not needed on android and by that the editor and compiler give includes errors.

#### error example:

[image]

I tryed to use the `#ifdef` preprocessor flags, configure cmake for android and configuring the adroid kit for Qt Creator, a'm able to compile and use another projects without problems than doesn't make use of specific libraries, but with this project it keep detecting linux of my machine, or there's something i'm wrong with??

##### project development machine:

`OS:` ARCH Linux x86_64
`KERNEL:` zen1-1zen
`CPU:` Intel i3-3110M 2.400GHz
`RAM:` 8GB DDR3L

##### deployment device:

`name:` Samsung Galaxy A31 5G
`OS:` ANDROID 12
`One UI version:` 4.1
`Kernel Version:` 4.14.186.24084238
`Chipset:` Mediatek MT6768 Helio P65
`CPU:` Octa-core (2x2.0 GHz Cortex-A75 & 6x1.7 GHz Cortex-A55)
`GPU:` Mali-G52 MC2
`RAM:` 4GB

sorry if i'm not clear enough!, english is not my native language, thank's for your patience.